# How to make "bundle install" run faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I need to add a new dependent gem in the Gemfile, then run "bundle install" it seems to take forever (sometimes 7 minutes for me).  How can I make this process faster?

I did a search on the web, and it mentioned a Gemfile.lock file.  That is appearing for me in my local directory.  But running "bundle install" still takes forever.

I've been learning Ruby on Rails for the past 2 weeks (so forgive the newby question, if the answer is obvious).

Comment: Seems like a long time, have you got a `source "http://rubygems.org"` in your gemfile? The docs are at http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Yes, source "http://rubygems.org" is at the top of my Gemfile

Comment: By the way, I'm using an Amazon EC2 micro instance.  I have no idea if this makes a difference.

Comment: @Chris That makes a big difference. Micro instances have low CPU/memory allotment, which means some gems will require much more time to install.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It [sounds like](http://blog.seqmedia.com/?p=294) they have made some changes in bundler 1.1 that are going to give some speed improvements so I would start by trying that:

```
mike@sleepycat:~$ sudo gem install bundler --prerelease
Fetching: bundler-1.1.pre.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.pre.1
1 gem installed
```

Comment: **Update** - Bundler 1.1 is in prerelease now and is indeed much faster. Here's an article explaining why: http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/14/why-bundler-1-1-will-be-much-faster

Answer (score 7):

This is "normal" behavior and is a pretty common complaint. Thoughtbot recently wrote a blog post that detailed the issue and has some suggestions on how to speed things up.

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/2729333530/fetching-source-index-for-http-rubygems-org

Answer (score 4):

From inside of your local directory, try

```
bundle config jobs 7
```

This will make bundle fetch jobs in parallel. 7 because I have 8 cpu cores. Generally, it should be one less than number of cpu cores you have.

This is supported from Bundler 1.4.0 onwards

Comment: I like to even replace the number with some Bash that returns the number of cores on the machine minus one (this is for Mac): `$(( $(sysctl -n hw.ncpu) - 1))`

Comment: Thank you so much as this thing solved my problem. My Pc is having 4 cores so I just used 3 jobs and did bundle install.

Comment: If you need to make the command compatible with Linux and Mac OS X I suggest to use `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` instead of `$(( $(sysctl -n hw.ncpu) - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can cache gems so bundler will not spend extra time for further checks during install/update

```
$ bundle package --no-prune --all
```