# Creating rails new app takes too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm new to Ror and I'm facing a problem
while creating new rails app by using this command:

> $ rails new test_app

it takes so long to execute it in bundle install process

Ps. I installed rails by using rbenv

gem ver: 2.4.5.1

ruby ver: ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]

rails ver: Rails 4.2.4

bundler ver: 1.10.6

Comment: `bundle install` depends on your Internet connection and system configuration because it downloads and installs the gems

Comment: thank you for response but I do have a pretty good internet connection of 10Mbps .. is there anyway to accelerate the bundle installation process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, instead of waiting you can cancel the progress and do `bundle install` manually. Follow these steps :-

- Run `rails new your_app`
- The command will generate all the files and at the last it implicitly runs `bundle install`, it will be shown in the terminal window.
- So there instead of waiting for it to complete, do `ctrl + c` and then manually run `bundle` command, you will notice that it takes much lesser time. Try it once!

Hope that helps!

Comment: well after I interpreted the installation process I went to the app directory and ran the command `$ bundle install`, but I got an error `Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-11.1.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (11.1.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '11.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.`

Comment: Something is wrong with the connection, try installing `rake` manually as suggested. `gem install rake -v '11.1.1'`, see if it works or not!

Comment: after installing the missing gem, everything seemed to be installed now.. thanks for support, it was very helpful :)

Comment: Also, you may skip `bundle install` using -B key, e. g. `rails new new_app -B`

Answer (score 2):

I've got another solution to this problem without interrupting the installation process by installing the last prerelease bundler by this command

> $ sudo gem install bundler --prerelease

Kindly follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227148/5394276). it executed the creation process in no time.